# Deciphering 1868 Irish marriage record?

Tags: palaeography, marriage-records, ireland, 1860s

I recently got a copy of my 3rd great grandfather's marriage certificate. He was married in the district of Drimoleague, union of Skibbereen, County Cork in Ireland in 1868. Most of the handwriting in the document is fairly legible, except for his residence.

Does anyone have any idea what it says?

[image: Florence McCarthy Marriage Certificate]

Answer (score 10):

[**Counkilla**](https://www.google.co.uk/maps/place/Counkilla,+Co.+Cork,+Ireland/@51.679086,-9.2729727,14z/) or Ceancullig (Gaelic: Ceann Coille) is located just north of Drimoleague. It is a townland in Drimoleague parish. Clearly there are numerous spelling variations of this place that you may find, some more phonetic, some more true to its Gaelic origin.

See the entry for Ceancullig on [Townlands.ie](https://www.townlands.ie/cork/west-carbery-east-division/dromoaleague/dromdaleague-north/ceancullig/) for more information about this location.

Historic maps for this area are freely viewable on the [Ordinance Survey Ireland website](http://maps.osi.ie/publicviewer/#V2,513516,548511,9,7). On the maps I viewed the name is spelled Ceancullig.

Comment: I just came to the same conclusion, Harry. The occupants of the townland for 1853 can be viewed at: http://www.askaboutireland.ie/griffith-valuation/index.xml?action=doNameSearch&PlaceID=286659&county=Cork&barony=Carbery,%20west%20(east%20division)&parish=Dromdaleague&townland=Ceancullig